# xarray conditional selection (xr.Dataset.where()) resets the dimension

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a netCDF dataset with unstructured grid where latitude and longitude are determined by a single dimension `ncells` from 0 to 32515.

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('idx_issue.nc')
ds
# output
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (ncells: 32516)
Coordinates:
    lon      (ncells) float64 178.6 181.4 184.2 187.0 ... 247.5 292.5 337.5 0.0
    lat      (ncells) float64 -78.05 -78.05 -78.05 -78.05 ... 88.59 88.59 90.0
Dimensions without coordinates: ncells
Data variables:
    hs       (ncells) float32 0.7366 0.7839 0.7732 ... 0.5916 1.032 0.8801
```

I was trying to selec based on the ncells values where the data variable is NaN. But as soon as I use `xr.Dataset.where()`, the index resets with the ncells values from 0 to 373 (number of NaN values in my dataset). In this subset of NaNs, the values of lat-lon for each ncell value does not correspond to lat-lon in the original dataset with the same ncell value:

```
ds.sel(ncells=100)

# output
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  ()
Coordinates:
    lon      float64 231.3
    lat      float64 -73.36
Data variables:
    hs       float32 2.314

####### cell with the same ncells value in the subset with NaNs only #######

ds.where(ds.hs.isnull(), drop=True).sel(ncells=100)

# output
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  ()
Coordinates:
    lon      float64 260.2
    lat      float64 78.98
Data variables:
    hs       float32 nan

####### subsetting based on the ncells where hs is NaN #######
test_idx = ds.where(ds.hs.isnull(), drop=True).ncells.values
ds.sel(ncells=test_idx)

# output
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (ncells: 374)
Coordinates:
    lon      (ncells) float64 178.6 181.4 184.2 187.0 ... 56.95 58.36 79.45
    lat      (ncells) float64 -78.05 -78.05 -78.05 ... -65.86 -65.86 -65.86
Dimensions without coordinates: ncells
Data variables:
    hs       (ncells) float32 0.7366 0.7839 0.7732 0.7689 ... 2.516 2.67 2.811  
# clearly the hs at those indices is not null ^^
```

I am not sure if I am doing it wrong or if it's a bug. I managed to get the expected result by converting ncells to MultiIndex, and saving original and new `ncells` to a dataframe and then performing selection based on the match between MultiIndex and the original ncells:

```
dsx = ds.set_index(ncells=('lon','lat'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'coords':dsx.ncells.values}, index=ds.ncells.values)
nan_idx = dsx.where(dsx.hs.isnull(), drop=True).ncells.values
keep = df[df.coords.isin(nan_idx)].index
nan_subset = ds.sel(ncells=keep)
nan_subset

# output
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (ncells: 374)
Coordinates:
    lon      (ncells) float64 303.0 300.2 301.6 303.0 ... 303.8 326.2 348.8
    lat      (ncells) float64 -75.7 -75.23 -75.23 -75.23 ... 87.66 87.66 87.66
Dimensions without coordinates: ncells
Data variables:
    hs       (ncells) float32 nan nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan


# correct subsetting ^^, but the resulting subset still reindexes ncells (doesn't affect what I am doing because I just want the result above but this is still bizzare) 

nan_subset.sel(ncells=100)

# output
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  ()
Coordinates:
    lon      float64 260.2
    lat      float64 78.98
Data variables:
    hs       float32 nan
```

The sample file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/168KdHk19YvIfi9JyB3BmD0ONFVVOzs14/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your ncells dimension does not have a corresponding set of coordinates/labels. Note the “dimensions without coordinates” indication. For such coordinates, you should not think of `.sel` as selecting labels but only selecting positionally - it operates the same way as `isel`. When you subset the data, the resulting dataset still does not have coordinates for this dimension, so subsequent selection operations are positional *using the new positions*.

If you would like to use label based indexing as you do in your code, you must first assign a coordinate to this dimension, e.g. using [`xr.Dataset.assign_coords`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.assign_coords.html):

```py
ds = ds.assign_coords(
    ncells=range(len(ds.ncells))
)
```